# Minimum number of tables required (E-R diagram)

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, database-normalization

[image]

a) Minimum number of tables required for the relation R to be in **1NF** .

b) Minimum number of tables required for the relation R to be in **3NF** .

c) Minimum number of tables required for the relation R to be in **4NF**.

---

**My attempt**

**a)** Here as we are just interested in **1NF**, in E1 we can have combined PK as AED.
   Now, we can combine E3 and E1 (Suppose it is R1) with new PK(Primary key) AEDB.
   We keep E2 as separate table with PK as C.

So according to me, we need **2 tables** R1(A,E,D,B) with AEDB as combined PK and E2(AC) with C as PK and A as FK for the relation R to be in **1NF**

**b)** I think the above split would also satisfy 3NF.

**c)** For 4NF, we need to put the multi-valued attributes E and D of E1 in separate table. So for 4NF the tables would be

R1(AB) with AB as combined Pk, R2(AE) with AE as combined PK, R3(AD) with AD as combined PK, R4(AC) with C as PK and A as FK.

So for **4NF**, we would require **4 tables** according to me.

I am not so sure about the answers for a) and b). Can someone please point out the mistakes if any?

Note :- Notations used here are standard ones used in Navathe book.

Comment: Normalization to higher NFs up to 4NF uses FDs & MVDs. Where are yours? And it doesn't use PKs. Also if you want us to answer it in terms you can use in homework/tests then you need to tell us what reference you are following. Also different ERDs use different notation so again, what is a reference?

Comment: This is standard notation from Navathe book. We are following even the relational mapping rules of Navathe.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy Ok. I just worked out one example based on the above diagram and found out we can combine all these tables into a single one for 1NF only if all relations are **totally participating**. I am not quite sure if it's correct.

Comment: Make sure you find out both necessary & sufficient conditions--so you can say you can join "if and only if". Also make sure you read & use "only if" correctly--it means the condition that follows is necessary but maybe not sufficient. PS What edition of Navathe?